# Question on dyes

Tags: combinatorics

Given 5 different green dyes,4 different blue dyes and 3 different red dyes the number of combinations does that can be chosen by taking at least one green and blue dyes is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of green dyes =5

Number of blue dyes=4

Number of red dyes =3

The required number of ways of choosing the dye is = 
$$
[(^2C_1)^5-1]*[(^2C_1)^4-1]*(^2C_1)^3=[2^5-1]*[2^4-1]*2^3\\=(32-1)*(16-1)*8=31*15*8=3720
$$
where each $^2C_1=2$ corresponds to selecting or not selecting a particular dye and subtracting with $1$ is to eliminate the case of not selecting all the particular dyes, i.e.$2^5-1$ which excludes the case of not selecting any green dye from all possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inclusion-exclusion here. Count the number of combinations without restrictions (you did not specify the number in a selection, so I can't do the computation for you). Subtract the number of selections without any green dye by redoing the compoutation after removing all gree dyes. Similarly subtract the number of selections without any blue dye. The selections with neither green nor blue dyes have been doubly subtracted, so need to be added back once to get the proper answer.